# Alarm manager for notification is not working properly

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I have used alarm manager in Android for showing some notifications, but it is not working properly.

My code in activity is:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, AlarmBroadcastReceiver.class);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, i, 0);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
        alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + (int) (10*60 * 1000),
                pendingIntent);
```

And the code for receiving a notification after 15 minutes is:

```
        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmBroadcastReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, intent, 0);
        am.cancel(pi);
        am.setExact(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
                SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() +
                        (int) ( 5*60 * 1000), pi);
```

Comment: whats the issue alarm didnt call even or other issue ?

Comment: i will guide how to do but for this i think it is better to use service instead of broadcast reciever.

Comment: alarm didn't call

Comment: I have tried with service also

Comment: `PendingIntent.getService()` in the second block should be `PendingIntent.getBroadcast()`. Aside from that, you need to explain exactly how it's not working.

Comment: in second code there should be getBroadcast

Comment: which device you are testing?

Comment: I have tested with different devices have different version.

Comment: Since there is no elaboration on not working properly, I suggest that you check notification volume on the device. Specially if you can see a notification but there is no sound.

Answer (score 1):

use this type of AlarmManager when you use service than you need to change getService insted of getBroadCast. sometime receiver not call and also creat issue in some devices when app in background

```
   Intent intent = new Intent(myContext, SetAlarmService.class);
            intent.putExtra("salah",i);
            intent.putExtra("repeat",HowManyTimeRepeatAlarm);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(
                    myContext, i, intent, 0);
            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) myContext.getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
           // alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
            alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, reset_cal.getTimeInMillis(),60000 * 2 ,
                    pendingIntent);
```

Comment: how can I stop the alarm if I use setRepeating.I need only 3 alarm

Comment: Shall I stop it from service itself?

Comment: you will stop service , by writing this code only stopself();